# Change "<a href" parameter from image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow select field:

```
<select name="country" class="country">
<option value="0">Select Country</option>
<option value="usa">USA</option>
<option value="japan">Japan</option>
</select>
```

and I would like to change on the fly the **a** url from an image.

Image code is:

```
<div class="container">

<a href="test.php">

<span class="image_wrap">
<img src="/image.png">
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

So when user select any country the **a href** url must have appended the country value as the follow (for example selecting "Japan"):

```
<a href="test.php?country=japan">
```

How to do that?

Comment: use onChange on the select field an then change the url of the a tag. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an event listener

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select[name="country"]');
const a = document.querySelector('.container > a');
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  a.href = 'test.php?country=' + select.value;
});
```

```html
<select name="country" class="country">
  <option value="0">Select Country</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="japan">Japan</option>
</select>

<div class="container">

  <a href="test.php">

    <span class="image_wrap">
<img src="http://test.com/image.png">
</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @CertainPerformance for your reply, it is exactly what I was looking for. Just a little extra help if possible: how to do if I have 2 select fields and 2 images (each one for each select)? For example: country and color?

Comment: Same thing, just make sure you can select each `select` distinctly (like how the one you posted has `<select name="country"`

Comment: thank you a lot! How to just append parameter data on link instead changing it entirely?

Comment: `=` is assignment, if you want concatenation, use `+=`